# HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED after upgrade in vs2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, dll

I have a project that was build in vc++ 6.Now I Upgrade it vs2008 and it build now perfect but when I open it from debug folder it also open but not execute because the related dll are not there.

Now I copied the exe in the other folder and the related dlls and try to open it the pop box open.[image]

Now there are 2 question in my mind that-

1. is there any file corrupt.
2. My dlls are the build in vc++6 environment.Should I upgrade the dlls also.

and may be there is another issue.
Please suggest!

Comment: I would build the DLLs with Visual Studio 2008 and see if it helps.  It's possible you have an issue with using different versions of the runtime to allocate and deallocate memory.  You could also click retry and see where the issue happened in the debugger.  It might give you some insight into the problem.

Comment: When I click on "retry" the pop box just close and nothing happaned

Comment: run it under the debugger and use the application verifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Build all projects and solutions in Visual C++ 2008, and carefully **remove** all higher level **warnings** (level 1 and level 2, at least).
- Run the programs from debugger (in debugging mode - i.e. <kbd>F5</kbd>, and not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>F5</kbd>)
- Run Debug build only. That too only 32-bit, in which you can edit-and-continue. For this you must enable `/DEBUG` linker option
- Try to narrow down the problem. Do step-by-step debugging and see where it fails. If it asserts, it is *good*, not bad! Look at the call stack and find the cause.
- Don't ignore exceptions, or hide them into try-catch blocks.

Answer (score 1):

stick to the rule:
Memory should be allocated and deallocated in the same module. Namely, donot allocate in dlls and deallocate in exes, vice versa.

You should check that which crt your project are using. Different CRT allocates memory in different ways, and many extra work will be done during the progress.

see:[Do (statically linked) DLLs use a different heap than the main program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820114/do-statically-linked-dlls-use-a-different-heap-than-the-main-program/10820518#10820518)

Maybe you should reconstruct your codes finally.