# Is it always safe to `free` a pointer returned by `malloc`?

Tags: c, malloc, free, allocation

My understanding is that it's allowed to call `free` with a pointer returned by a call to `malloc` (or any other function returning a pointer to some memory dynamically allocated on a heap, like `strdup` or `asprintf`) only if it's known that both functions operate on the same heap. As a consequence, I understand that "general approach" should be to provide a complementary deallocation routine rather than calling `free` on any pointer we've been returned from a function which allocated it, because in general case we never know if the pointer has been passed by any boundaries of whatever-can-affect-it. I think that calling `free` directly on a pointer we were handed in should be more of a *special* case, when we know *for sure* that the pointer we hold is safe to `free` by us (for example, we `strdup`-ed or `malloced` it ourselves, or we know that the routine which allocated it is somewhere "close" and the pointer did not pass any boundaries).

However, it's been very long since I've been doing any professional C, and when I had, it was not much, so I could just know wrong. I am confronted by many opinions that calling `free` on any (valid, non-freed) malloced pointer is generally safe, and custom deallocation routines should be used only when explicitly known to be necessary. But this somehow stands in contrast to my memories of using Visual Studio 6 on Windows where success of calling `free` on an arbitrary, known-to-be-malloced pointer depended on a place in a three-dimensional compatibility matrix of "statically/dynamically linked runtime", "debug/release build" and "single-/multi-threaded runtime" of allocating and deallocating parties.

My question is then: what are general, and practical, rules to calling `free` on a pointer which I know for sure has been `malloc`-ed, and not `free`-d yet? When is it safe, and more importantly, when is it not? If I create a function which returns a `malloc`-ed pointer, should I always provide a separate function which frees it, or is it (in general case) enough to say *"deallocate the returned memory by calling `free` on the pointer I just  returned to you"*? How probable is, from practical point of view, running into a situation that calls to `malloc` and `free` operate on incompatible heaps, or are not symmetric in any other way? Let's assume that the pointer points to some trivial piece of data, and not to some opaque structure which holds some additional book-keeping information and needs some complex logic to deallocate the used memory.

Comment: There's only one heap used by all `malloc()` and `free()` calls. There are other ways of allocating memory, like `mmap()`. But if the memory was allocated with `malloc()`, you can safely free it with `free()`.

Comment: If a function returns a pointer, the documentation should say whether the caller is expected to free it.

Comment: You can free it *once* with `free()`. If you are in doubt about the sequence of events, you can then set the pointer to `NULL` which is safe to pass to `free()` (and which will create a clear identifiable problem if you then continue to dereference it).

Comment: Some libraries provide their own "cleanup" function, which takes care of freeing anything that should be freed. Again, the documentation should explain what you're supposed to do with the data returned.

Comment: @Barmar OP has likely been confused by Microsoft's run time libraries, which perversely can and do use multiple heaps.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820114/do-statically-linked-dlls-use-a-different-heap-than-the-main-program for just one example.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I do not understand your use of the word "confused" - the post you linked seems to describe the situation which I (IIRC) encountered in practice, so it seems to support my idea that `malloc` and `free` are not symmetric _in general_. Where exactly am I confused?

Comment: Why does the number of heaps matter? One `malloc`, one `free`.

Comment: @Maciek C language wise it is always safe. If one program uses many different implementations of malloc (as it is in Windows) then of course it is not C compliant program. This your confusion malloc != malloc in windows depending on the library used.

Comment: In the linked question the advice is not to mix the library types.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from not differentiating between standard C and particular implementation(s) like e.g. Microsoft CRT. Since in your question you just tagged C and don't mention any particular implementation you will get answers about standard C which only deals with  the abstract machine and where concepts like "heap" or dlls don't exist. But from your comment it's clear to me you meant to ask about about real life concrete compiler and library implementations.

Comment: Well, if I already knew that it's a problem with an implementation, I wouldn't have to ask the question in the first place because I would already know the answer (or, at least, a part of it). It's also not immediately clear if Microsoft CRT is the only implementation suffering from the problem. After all, a linux program which uses modules which link different runtimes in different ways (like each module linking its own runtime statically) would suffer from the same problem, wouldn't it? Or things work differently on linux in this regard?

Answer (score 4):

> ... what are general, and practical, rules to calling `free` ...?
> When is it safe, and more importantly, when is it not?

`free(NULL)` is always O. K.

Otherwise:

- Calling `free()`, once, on any pointer from `malloc(), calloc(), realloc(), strdup(), aligned_alloc()` is OK and well defined.
- After a pointer has been free'd, do not free it again.
- Do not attempt to de-reference a free'd pointer.
- With these functions there is no incompatible *heap* concern.
- Do not call `free()`on other pointers that originate elsewhere.

Comment: You might add: do not dereference a pointer that has been freed: accessing the memory in a freed block has undefined behavior.

Comment: @chqrlie OK.  Pedantically even copying a free'd pointer is technical UB, but I do not want to [die on that hill](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hill_to_die_on) and so will only mention it here.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think he was asking about weird windows libraries :)

Answer (score 1):

> running into a situation that calls to malloc and free operate on
> incompatible heaps, or are not symmetric in any other way? Let's
> assume that the pointer points to some trivial piece of data, and not
> to some opaque structure which holds some additional book-keeping
> information and needs some complex logic to deallocate the used
> memory.

The `C` language does not know anything about the heap. It knows only objects storage durations. Objects created by `malloc` family functions have *allocated storage duration*. An *allocated storage duration* object exists until it if freed by calling `free` function. So the conforming program should `free` any `malloc`ed memory safe

If your program is not conforming and uses many different implementations of `malloc` (ie dynamic library uses a different one than your main program) it is obvious that your main program `free` should not be used on object allocated by the different implementations of `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that this is from the `Library Functions Manual` on Linux. I don't know if/how VSC is different.

```
The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which must have
been returned by a previous call to malloc() or related functions. Otherwise,
or if ptr has already been freed, undefined behavior  occurs. If ptr is NULL,
no operation is performed.
```

TLDR yeah, as long as you're not doing so more than once per pointer.